# a cold vs flu / the flu

Tags: indefinite-articles, definite-articles

**Have you got a cold?

Have you got flu?

Have you got the flu?**

Why can't we say *a flu* or *the cold* in the previous examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can precede *cold* with both *a* and *the* when we make a generic reference, as in ‘A cold can be difficult to get rid of in the winter’, and ‘The common cold is found everywhere in the world.’ In conversation we use *a cold* when we introduce it as a new topic of conversation (‘I’ve got a cold’), but *the* when we refer to it once it’s been mentioned (‘How long have you had the cold?’)

The reason why we say, or can say, *the flu* in contexts where we have to say *a cold* has its origins in the word’s history. *Influenza* is an Italian word having the basic meaning of ‘influence’, but which came to mean ‘visitation’ and ‘outbreak’ and then ‘epidemic’. Its first recorded use in English was in 1743:

> News from Rome of a contagious Distemper raging there, call'd the
>   *Influenza*.

The definite article has been possible ever since. In actual fact, influenza occurs mostly with the zero article, as [this nGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=influenza,the%20influenza&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows.

Comment: Re your last sentence, OP asked about **flu**, not **influenza**. And as [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+flu%2Chas+the+flu&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows, *"has the flu"* is far more common than *"has flu"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Good point. Still, I think I would always omit 'the' myself.

Comment: Yeah, I probably would myself. Referring to someone having *the flu* sounds a bit dated/rustic to me - like saying they've got the plague or something.

Comment: As a native speaker of American English, I find *How long have you had **a** cold?* unremarkable (perfectly acceptable) even after it has been introduced into the discourse. Also, in fact, we can say *How long have you had **the cold**?* to bring up (introduce) the person's cold as a topic.

Answer (score 2):

Because there are many colds, but only one flu. The flu has always been considered a disease, but it is only very recently that the cold has also been considered so. Originally, catching a cold was believed to be just something that happened to you based on enviromental conditions - like a headache. Even now, worried parents will warn their children that if they get cold and wet, they are likely to catch a cold, which we now know to be entirely incorrect.

So every cold was a separate thing, unique to the person who had it - saying "I've got the cold" would be like saying "I've got the headache". A case of the flu on the other hand was NOT separate, but a part of the larger flu outbreak.

Comment: I this this is right. What we are saying is "I have the influenza virus", and "I have a cold virus". Of course, often flu is misused, to mean "an influenza-like illness", which confuses the issue, but these are not proper influenza.

Comment: There is not one flu: influenza is a classification of many sub-types of flu virus - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influenza#Types_of_virus

Comment: @msanford: I'm sure what Benubird means is that in any given year, one particular strain of flu is far more likely to pass through any given country than other strains. This is what enables the medical profession to plan ahead and give all our elderly people the appropriate vaccine every autumn. And getting even more localised, almost everyone who succumbs in some particular town, for example, will be catching the same strain as others falling sick around the same time in that area. So it's **the** flu of the moment.

Comment: So why is it "the bends" but just "chills"? I'm sorry, I just don't believe this.

Answer (score 0):

The way articles are used in English is basically unpredictable. We just have a sense that some words require particular articles and some require other ones and some require none at all. They defy any attempt to find a logical pattern.

This isn't a satisfying answer, but it's all we've got. Why do we say "going to the Amazon River" but "going to Lake Ontario"? We say "a hernia", "the bends", and just plain "emphysema".

**Update**: You'll notice in the comments that people keep trying to make up rules to explain this, but the rules are either correct as often as they're incorrect or just list the cases and say what happens in each case. There's simply no pattern to it.

Comment: "going to the Amazon River" is equivalent to "going to the Ontario Lake". The difference is that "the Amazon River" means the river in the Amazon, while "Lake Ontario" means the lake named Ontario.

Comment: That's nonsense. The Amazon River has, as its proper name, "Amazon River". It is *not* "the river in the Amazon" because in that case, "river" would not be capitalized. In any event, even if this were correct, it wouldn't tell us anything because it tells us nothing about *why* rivers are different from lakes. It would still be saying "rivers are, lakes aren't, and that's that". (And while you *could* say "the Ontario Lake", you *must* say "the Amazon River". The difference is purely arbitrary. One just is, one just isn't. Period.)

Comment: No, this is a part of the structure of the name. When a name is of the format "Identifier Type" (e.g. amazon river) it must be prefixed with "the". When a name is of the format "type identifier" (e.g. lake ontario), it doesn't need the article. "hernia" describes an object, "bends" is plural, and "emphysema" is a base case.

Comment: @Benubird: Yes, you can give all these characteristics names. That doesn't give them any rhyme or reason. Why are rivers always "identifier types"? Why are lakes "type identifiers"? Why does "hernia" describe an object rather than the condition of having one as "cancer" does? Why must you say "I have the bends" but you can say "I have chills"? They're both plural. Your explanation doesn't actually explain anything.

Comment: I don't know why they're usually "identifier type". Presumably some historic reason, but that's beyond the scope here - I'm not trying to say why it's "amazon river" not "river amazon", only answering why the first version is prefixed with "the" and the second isn't. I don't know why "hernia" is an object not a condition, but because it is, is the reason you say "a hernia". Note that "I have cancer" means the disease, and "I have A cancer" means a specific tumor. Similarly "I have a hernia" and "I have herniation". Why "cancer", not "canceration"? I don't know. Why "mice" and not "mouses"?

Comment: Also, on an almost irrelevant note... I don't think I've ever heard someone say "I have chills", only "I have the chills", e.g. "that gives me the chills".

Comment: @Benubird: You didn't answer why one version is prefixed by "the" and the other isn't. You just gave one name for names prefixed by "the" and another name for one's that aren't. That doesn't tell us anything, other than your guess that it's for "some historic reason". All you've done is name each case. And if you Google "have chills", you'll find hundreds of thousands of such uses, including of course the song from Grease, "You're The One That I Want" which starts, "I've got chills". Yes, "a cancer" means some specific tumor, but *why*? You don't need to say "a flu" to mean a specific flu.

Comment: @Benubird: The OP's question is basically "How can I tell whether to use 'a', 'the', or nothing?" And my answer is simply that there is no way to tell, English follows no rule for this. Your answer is just to name the cases, which doesn't help. Given name for a disease or place, how do I know which case it falls into? And the answer is that you just have to know. It simply must be "the bends" but it can be just "chills". There is no rule that will allow you to tell this other than knowing that the terms are just different.

Comment: Grammar is a list of cases, with rules for how to identify that case, and how to handle it. That's what I'm giving you - for correct usage, you don't need to know why case X is prefixed by "the" and Y isn't, only that they are, and how to identify them. Example rule: If the name is of the form "Identifier Type", prefix it with "the". There's your rule. "I've got chills" is grammatically incorrect, like "I ain't telling you nothing" or ending a sentence with a preposition. Just because something is common doesn't make it right. English DOES have rules, even if you don't know them.

Comment: @Benubird: You can tell millions of people who say "gives me chills" that you are right and they are wrong. But they *cannot* be wrong. A language is how it is used. And many names of the form "identifier type" get no "the". Gibson House, but the Reagan Library. South America, but the northern lights. Elm Street, but the Oregon Trail.