# Is "flu" the only disease usually accompanied with "the"?

Tags: articles

Is "flu" the only disease usually accompanied with "the"? From what I understand, you don't usually use "the" with diseases / illnesses / disorders ("have Alzheimer's / diarrhea / claustrophobia / dyslexia, etc." not "have the..."), but it's perfectly normal to say "have the flu". Is the flu the only exception?

**Edit (this is only a side part, and can be glossed over if you will, so it's not a duplicate imo):** What's so significant about the flu that other conditions don't have, so that it's entitled to "the"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a cold vs flu / the flu](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60684/a-cold-vs-flu-the-flu)

Comment: People used to die *from **the** plague* at least as often as they died *from plague*. And somewhat more recently (when I was a kid back in the 50s) it was perfectly natural to say someone had [*caught **the** measles*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22caught+the+measles%22).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It seems that adding *the* to some diseases like that is still common; see [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=caught+flu%2Ccaught+the+flu%2Ccaught+measles%2Ccaught+the+measles%2C+caught+plague%2C+caught+the+plague&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccaught%20flu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaught%20the%20flu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaught%20measles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaught%20the%20measles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaught%20plague%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaught%20the%20plague%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not a duplicate. That one asks why 'the flu' instead of just 'flu', this asks any others like 'the flu'

Comment: It's not uncommon for someone with gout to call it "the gout."

Comment: So in the US when you have the flu you go to the hospital.  But in the UK when you have flu you go to hospital.  Right?

Comment: @davidbak I’ve seen no evidence that one version is more common on one side of the pond than on the other.

Comment: the plague, the measles, the mumps...just off the top of my head.

Comment: There is also Spike Milligan's 'the dreaded lurgi'.

Comment: @EJP beat me to it while digging up a link. +1 for spelling.

Comment: There's also the clap

Comment: When you move in right up close to me... That's when I get the shakes all over me...

Comment: Avoid hasty generalizations like the plague.

Comment: [I think I've got the black lung pop *cough* *cough*](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/ae/aeec73c54f6e594b49bb0d75de12fb4a1856285c90d81a76ba6cd796e5c79638.jpg)

Comment: the clap, the pest, the plague, the runs...

Answer (score 88, accepted):

#### TLDR:

Using the definite article before names of ailments was more common
historically than today. Even so, people still say *the measles* and *the mumps* about as often
as they say  *the flu*, and you sometimes come upon others
like *the gout*, *the cancer*, and *the rheumatism*, especially in dialogue meant to represent older or more rustic speech.

The OED records that this
“*ᴛʜᴇ*-disease” version began over a thousand years ago, and
notes that both styles coëxist today. A secondary and sometimes more humorous subsense has since arisen in expressions like *the blues, the creeps,* and *the jitters*.

---

## The Historical Record

Once upon a time, one [***used*** to speak of *the influenza*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20influenza%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1834&lr=lang_en), so it is only natural that this would have become shortened up to *the flu*.

Many diseases were once commonly used with the definite article preceding their names in English over the past thousand years.  Some still get talked about that way, often with both styles existing side by side in Present Day English. Jump to the section ***Free Samples, Often Funny*** towards the end of this post for copious examples of these, some with links.

The OED talks about this particular use of the article *the* in its two related subsenses for sense 8, the one technical and the other risible, with the text set in bold my own markup:

> 8a. With the names of diseases, ailments, etc.
>
>        **Still in common use** side by side with forms without the definite article.
>
> 8b. With **colloq. or humorous** names of afflictions, as *the blues, collywobbles, creeps, D.T.’s, habdabs, heebie-jeebies, jitters,* etc., q.v. Hence in analogous **nonce-expressions**.

The earliest citation provided is from Old English in 1000 ᴀ.ᴅ.; later citations include *the cold, the croup, the fever, the stone, the German measles*. So influenza is hardly unique.

In scientific journals you will see often see diseases referred to as *the X virus*, such as with *influenza* or *smallpox* or *rubella*, but when you drop the “virus” part, you also now normally drop the article.

But first before we talk about where we are now, let’s remember where we came from by looking at some of what Mitch would call [arthrous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arthrous) uses. That is, those with the article before them.

## That Was Then

So using ***the*** in front of diseases, ailments, and other assorted afflictions used to be perfectly normal.   For example, in [Volume 1 of The Baltimore Medical and Philosophical Lycæum from  1811](https://goo.gl/eg9VEM) we find this reference:

> I mention this more particularly, because in **the influenza** of 1790, Dr. Rush remarks that in several cases blood-letting produced alarming results.

And in [*The Obstetrical Journal of Great Britain and Ireland* of 1875](https://goo.gl/b3sbVL) we find this:

> - [...] because **the croup** and **the measles** appeared at the same time: [...]

And in [*Famine in Tudor and Stuart England* published in 1975](https://goo.gl/yJbu9E) we find a reprint from an account originally from a couple centuries earlier reading:

> - At times these and other afflictions came and also **the bloody flux** which put people in such a plight that countless died of it.

And here from [1831 in *The Journal of Health*](https://goo.gl/u92PWC) with both *the catarrh* and *the influenza* as was then the common use:

> - In proffering a few remarks on **the epidemic catarrh**, or **the influenza**, which has of late prevailed over so great an extent of country, [...]

## This Is Now

When *the Black Death* scourged Europe, it was commonly called *the Great Plague* or *the awful pest*, with the latter giving rise to the organism we now know to have caused it, *Yersinia **pest**is*.

Today you would be more likely to hear someone talk about *plague* than to hear them talk about ***the** plague*. From the plague-inpested prairie-dog towns of my backyard in [Boulder County, Colorado](http://www.bouldercounty.org/family/disease/pages/plague.aspx) comes this warning:

> - **Plague** is a bacterial disease transmitted by the fleas of rodents and is widespread in the western United States. **Plague** commonly infects prairie dogs and squirrels that can be found in parks and residential areas within Boulder County. Household pets, such as dogs and especially cats, can either get **plague** or carry infected fleas home to their owners.

This sounds perfectly natural here:

> What killed off the prairie dog colony? Did they poison them?
>
> No, it was **the plague** again.

## Free Samples, Often Funny

The secondary, “humorous” use of *the* that the OED mentions is now commonly associated with references to the sufferer’s symptoms, such as in many of these:

- [the bends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompression_sickness)
- the (bloody) flux
- [the bug](http://dare.wisc.edu/survey-results/1965-1970/health-and-disease/bb10)
- [the cancer](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22got%20the%20cancer%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)
- [the catarrh](https://goo.gl/u92PWC)
- the chills
- [the clam](https://www.stdcheck.com/blog/std-slang-terms/)
- the clap
- the cough
- [the croup](https://goo.gl/b3sbVL)
- the drip
- the dropsy
- the (dry) heaves
- the flu
- [the (German) measles](http://www.empowher.com/measles/content/difference-between-rubella-and-rubeola)
- the giggles
- the gout
- [the gripe, grippe, grip](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grippe)
- the hives
- the itch
- the mumps
- the palsy
- [the pest](https://en.oxforddictionaries.comdefinition/pest)
- the piles
- the plague
- the pox
- [the rheumatism](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20rheumatism%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)
- the runs
- the shakes
- the shits
- the sneezes
- the spots
- the squirts
- the sweats
- the trots

Some of those come off as perfectly normal casual expressions, while others are mildly archaizing—a bit quaint as Janus mentions.

#### Summary

Saying *the flu* is a holdover from older styles of talking about illnesses and other physical troubles; people used to get *the influenza*. This practice was more common formerly than in Present Day English, where the habit—but not the rule—is to drop the article for most of these.

The casual terms amongst those listed above do seem to retain their article more than the official disease names. These euphemisms may be more noticeable in some regions an registers than in others.

---

#### Notes

Credit to Janus for suggesting the article usage might sometimes come off as a bit precious, and to Alan for suggesting the OED reference. Credit to Mitch for *arthrous*.

Comment: (West-coast) American English speaker here: Most of these are unacceptable to me.

Comment: @errantlinguist I can hardly blame you: I wouldn’t want them either.

Comment: Often these express *symptoms* of a disease and are more informal than the normal names for them. The only ones that I think aren't related to symptoms are **the flu** and **the plague**.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey, yes, (at least to me), *the `ailment`* is generally more acceptable than *the `disease`*, e.g. *he's got the clap* vs. *he's got chlamydia* (# *he's got **the** chlamydia* is ungrammatical). Most of these terms, however, are somehow so "general" that they aren't semantically acceptable, e.g. \**I've got the itch* --- well, *what* itch?

Comment: Of these, the only ones that are diseases that are still referred to arthrously are: the flu, the plague, and the clap. All the others I would naturally say with out the definite article, are symptoms, or archaic (which may or may not be anarthrous: the shits, but hives)

Comment: @Mitch wow, really? As an AmE speaker, to me *the mumps*, *the measles*, and many others are most natural with the article. The OED mentions that "With names of diseases, ailments, etc. [*the* is] [s]till in common use side by side with forms without the definite article"  Usage changes over time, and the OED gives instances of *the influenza*.

Comment: @errantlinguist Most of these sound all right (if in some cases perhaps a little quaint) to me with the definite article. I agree _the itch_ is too general to be definite (I presume it’s a slang term I don’t know for some specific condition); other than that, I’d expect _the drips_ in the plural, and I’ve never heard _the piles_ in the definite before. I’ve never heard anyone talk about ‘the’ palsy before, either—that’s like _itch_, too broad: _what_ palsy? The rest all sound quite normal with the definite article to me, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet 'The palsy' is archaic but well-attested. KJV: "And his fame went throughout all Syria: and they brought unto him all sick people that were taken with divers diseases and torments, and those which were possessed with devils, and those which were lunatick, and those that had the palsy; and he healed them." (Matthew 4:24)

Comment: Cancer is occasionally *the cancer* in certain dialects. I don't say it, but have seen and heard it in the US.

Comment: Dang! Your answer was decent and to the point, but now I'd definitely upvote for it again!

Comment: Though, not necessarily a disease, Southern women are often afflicted with "the vapors". ;)

Comment: Great answer, *except* that the reference to "the influenza of 1790" is out of place. In that instance the writer clearly meant *a specific epidemic of* influenza. Similarly, we say "the earthquake of 1906" or "the panic of 1873" but that doesn't imply that "the earthquake" or "the panic" are common idioms on their own. (We are vaccinated against *the flu*, but we do not reinforce our buildings against *the earthquake*.) [Google results for "the cholera of"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+cholera+of%22) seem to reinforce my intuition here.

Comment: Worth noting that the usage can be very colloquial, *the flu*, for example, is pretty widely used. But in Western Irish rural areas it is quite usual to hear the definite article applied in other places also, such as *to see the mammy* or *to eat the dinner*, etc

Comment: I logged in to write the same thing that I've just noticed Quuxplusone has already said.

Comment: “Today you would be more likely to hear someone talk about *plague* than to hear them talk about ***the** plague*.” Can we get some data on that? I wouldn’t say that *the plague* is as automatic as *the flu*, *the measles*, or *the mumps* (or, for that matter, *the clap*), but I feel like I hear *the plague* more than just *plague*.

Comment: I thought the use of "the flu" or "the cold" is a reference to the current strain like "the bug" currently going around the office.

Comment: Excellent comprehensive answer, but did you forget "the heebie-jeebies"?

Comment: And one that I remember being mentioned by a farmer during travels in Northern Ireland, "the (dreaded) orf" :-)  -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orf_(disease)

Answer (score 11):

There's also [*the bends*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_bends) (decompression sickness), [*the pock*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_pock) (smallpox).

It seems that informal names of diseases can take *the*.

Comment: Though the bends is not a disease, any more than a sunburn or a broken arm is.

Comment: @jamesqf the bends surely is a disease, in fact, [it also goes by the names of 'divers' disease' and 'caisson disease'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompression_sickness) and its formal name is - as this post says - decompression sickness, 'sickness' being defined as ['a particular disease or malady'](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sickness)

Comment: @jamesqf - But only that cute girl on Teen Titans would say "the sunburn" or "the broken arm".

Comment: @Au101 Well, how do you know "the bends" is a disease rather than a malady?

Comment: @Au101: No, a disease is something caused by a living organism: usually a bacterium or virus, sometimes more exotic things such as prions or the body's own immune system going haywire.  The bends is an accident.  Calling it a disease makes no more sense than saying that hitting your finger with a hammer is a disease.

Comment: @jamesqf I'd say that if you intentionally hit your finger with a hammer, that's a stupidity disease.

Comment: @jamesqf Is this a technical distinction in medicine? In common usage there is no stipulation that it must be caused by a living organism. ["A disorder of structure or function in a human, animal, or plant, especially one that produces specific symptoms or that affects a specific location and is not simply a direct result of physical injury"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disease). I suppose you and I could argue the philosophical point of whether the bends should count as 'physical injury' - I myself think it's more reserved for the hammer situation

Comment: @jamesqf But you have it on as good authority as [the diseases database](http://www.diseasesdatabase.com/ddb3491.htm) that it is also known as caisson disease, so for the purposes of this question, I think it surely counts

Comment: @jamesqf -- Your definition of disease is clearly wrong, as it precludes several conditions that are universally considered to be diseases, including cancer, diabetes, and asbestosis.

Answer (score 2):

When you use *influenza*, the *the* is not broadly used compared with *flu*.

Ngram Viewer: [catch influenza vs catch the influenza](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catch+influenza%2Ccatch+the+influenza&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccatch%20influenza%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccatch%20the%20influenza%3B%2Cc0) / [caught influenza vs caught the influenza](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=caught+the+influenza%2Ccaught+influenza%2C+catch+influenza%2C+catch+the+influenza&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccaught%20the%20influenza%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaught%20influenza%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccatch%20influenza%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccatch%20the%20influenza%3B%2Cc0) / [suffer from influenza, suffer from the influenza](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suffer+from+influenza%2C+suffer+from+the+influenza&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuffer%20from%20influenza%3B%2Cc0) and [caught the flu vs caught flu](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=caught+the+flu%2C+caught+flu&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccaught%20the%20flu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaught%20flu%3B%2Cc0) / [catch the flu vs catch flu](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catch+the+flu%2C+catch+flu&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccatch%20the%20flu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccatch%20flu%3B%2Cc0)

Other diseases that use the definite article:

- [the blues](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blues): a feeling of sadness or depression

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49151/discussion-on-answer-by-rathony-is-flu-the-only-disease-usually-accompanied-wi).

Answer (score 2):

Etymology can help comprehend the use of the article.

As a label, "the flu" is short for **"the influence"** (only now we know it's viral, not by the stars):

Merriam-Webster, on the [origin and etymology of "influenza"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/influenza):

*"Italian, literally, **influence,** from Medieval Latin influentia; from the belief that epidemics were due to the influence of the stars".*

Outside the context of illness, ["influence"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/influence) is a common noun of potentially desirable effects as well,

*"the act or power of producing an effect without apparent exertion of force or direct exercise of command",*

There would not be so much of this potential for "plaguing"; the label is **the** plague, for it is specifically *[the bubonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubonic_plague)* ("bubonic" being an adjective).

Further, we might say "symptoms of **the/ this** flu", in comparative contexts; we yet mostly say "symptoms of flu", without the definite article, as per this [Google search](https://www.google.ie/search?q=%22symptoms%20of%20flu%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gws_rd=cr&ei=L5k-WOL5IOSDgAaDh4CwCA).

Description of symptoms usually comes **after** the ailment has been labeled.

Answer (score 1):

You could also say someone has the black plague (which still exists today, in rare cases).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/210330)

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey - yes, it does.  The question was whether any disease other than Influenza is commonly used with the definite article; this answer provides an example of another disease where it is used, thus showing that "the flu" is not the only such disease.

Comment: It does provide an answer to the question, but it would be vastly improved by adding a citation demonstrating that *the black plague* is indeed used. After all, a bald statement that "you could say someone has the alopecia" is not incorrect -- even though *the alopecia* would be. [Pun not intended!]