# When does a disease require an article?

Tags: definite-articles

This is a two part question. First part: a few diseases require or allow an article (the flu, the measles, the shingles), but most do not permit it (polio, diarrhea, cancer, COPD). You can test this in the sentence: "Last year I had [the][disease]". What determines when an article is not permitted or required before the name of a disease?

Second part: If someone does use an article in front of a disease that normally does not need one-- "In January my cousin got the Covid"--is this more than just a solecism? It might not be an error, but rather a style of speech. But it implies, to me, that the speaker is uneducated or from a lower economic class.

Comment: Without commenting on elitism, I have heard highly educated friends consistently say "That makes me feel badly."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "flu" the only disease usually accompanied with "the"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360387/is-flu-the-only-disease-usually-accompanied-with-the) See also [Which article is correct when referring to a disease eg the flu; a cold](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/485249/which-article-is-correct-when-referring-to-a-disease-e-g-the-flu-a-cold). Essentially, correctness is idiosyncratic. I'd say 'the COVID' is non-standard. You can run checks on Google ngrams.

Comment: 1) No one has mentioned (in all the possible duplicates) that you get "__a__ cold''. 2) I have often heard slangily __"the 'rona"__ as short for the "co __rona__ virus" and maybe 'the covid' is out of analogy. Maybe?

Comment: @Mitch The very **title** of the second link in my comment is 'Which article is correct when referring to a disease eg the flu; a cold?'

Comment: I clearly should have researched the site prior to posting my question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth haha...I can't read. Well, I didn't see it in the half read articles I did open.

Comment: Are there any other diseases that just use 'a'? A headache? A broken arm? A fever?