# In the sentence "I have the hiccups", could the "the" article be omitted?

Tags: grammar, articles

I work as a tutor for an online English school and one student asked me this:

"In this sentence: I have the hiccups

Could it be: I Have hiccups?"

I have done a lot of research on advanced article usage but I haven't found anything even close to that. I have no idea what to say.

Any help will be appreciated. Especially if you can suggest articles about this subject.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

It is not a duplicate to [a cold vs flu / the flu discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60684/a-cold-vs-flu-the-flu) because talking about having "hiccups" is not the same as talking about having "flu".

Comment: For your specific "condition", usage has been pretty much [evenly split this past half-century.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+the+hiccups%2Chave+hiccups&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20the%20hiccups%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20hiccups%3B%2Cc0) It's entirely your choice.

Comment: A couple other options: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+the+hiccups%2Cgot+hiccups%2Chave+the+hiccups%2Chave+hiccups&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20the%20hiccups%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20hiccups%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20the%20hiccups%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20hiccups%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The "the" is optional.

Comment: "I have the hiccups" is a description of what's happening at the moment.  To speak generally: "When I have hiccups, I sip water from the opposite side of the glass, and that usually works."